# Hibernation stopped working after changing the swap partition

Tags: partitioning, 16.04, swap, hibernate

I usually always do `sudo pm-hibernate` to save my development session. Now I recently switched to ubuntu and since then I always run into some hibernation trouble.

Sometimes the system would crash and I didn't know why. But today I found out that my swap partition was too small.

Gparted didn't allow me to resize my swap partition but I still had space left on my sdd so I created a new partition with sufficient space as `linux-swap`

It is now on /dev/sdb3 and I updated /etc/fstab accordingly

```
UUID=79e3657d-48b6-4a7b-83b5-214550ea1109 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

> ➜   blkid /dev/sdb3
>   /dev/sdb3: UUID="79e3657d-48b6-4a7b-83b5-214550ea1109" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="601ef3d8-03"

Buw now if I do `sudo pm-hibernate`, nothing really happens. It is as if I would have done a restart. So I assume that updating fstab with the new swap partition wasn't enough?

```
➜  ~ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7965        1229        5882          41         854        6466
Swap:          9988           0        9988
```

Comment: See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/671941/how-can-i-redetect-swap-partition-after-formating-to-enable-hibernation?rq=1). It may help you in your case.

Comment: @AshharHasan Sadly that did not work, now if I resume hibernation, I only see a black screen.

Comment: Are you by any chance on kernel 4.4.0. It seems to have broken hibernation. Try using `sudo systemctl hibernate` on either kernel 4.2.x or 4.4.8 or later. It works for me on 4.2.x and 4.4.8. `pm-utils` is not the recommended way to hibernate though since it has been unmaintained since 2013.

Comment: Try turning on logging for `pm-utils`. From a superuser shell, `PM_DEBUG=true pm-hibernate`. Paste the output in the file `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` in your answer. And please report what happens if you try to use `systemctl hibernate`.

Comment: Yep `systemctl hibernate` works

Comment: Ok. Same here. I think I'll file a bug to `pm-utils` package but that may not have much going because the package seems to be unmaintained.